# Zend Routing:: How I can send all request that going to application-> IndexController to application->module->store->IndexController

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-route

How I can send all request in zend project to my default module controller (without use .access files).

Now it going to **application->IndexController**, Instead I need that every request will go to **application->module->store->IndexController**.

I try this:

```
public function indexAction()
{
       $this->_forward('index','index','store');
}
```

Its works, but url in web browser http://localhost/mystore/public/ not change to http://localhost/mystore/public/store/

Thanks,

Yosef

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->_redirect('index','index','store');
}
```

Looking forward, probably the controller plugin handling automatically all the redirects will be better.

Comment: thanks, Its works with little change:

$this->_redirect('store');